# "Trivial" extension of functional bounded?

Tags: functional-analysis

Suppose I am in $\ell^{\infty}$ and define the $\lim$ functional on the subspace of convergent sequences. Is the "trivial" extension which is zero on all non convergent sequences a bounded functional on $\ell^{\infty}$? I cant see why not, and cant come up with an argument against it.

Comment: It's not linear.

Comment: Consider its action on $(1,0,1,0,\ldots)$, $(0,1,0,1,\ldots)$ and their sum.

Comment: @DavidMitra nither are convergent ?  same for their sum? hence its zero on both sides?

Comment: The sum is $(1,1,\ldots)$...

Comment: @DavidMitra right, I was stuck on sums for the $\ell^{p}$ norms

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The extension does not even define a linear functional as one can see from the comments. Consider the two sequencese $a=(1,0,1,..)$ and $b=(0,1,0,..)$. Applying $\ell$ gives us $0=\ell(a)+\ell(b)\ne \ell(a+b)=1$.

Comment: @G.Sassatelli Im sorry I dont see how this donst answer my question. If something is suppose to be a bounded linear functional, showing that its not even a linear functional seattles it.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://math.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://math.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/549191)

Comment: @User1 I agree with you, which is why I voted not to delete, but it's good practice to make the answer as self-contained as is reasonable. Here, that would entail adding the counterexample from the comments to the answer. You should also mark the question as answered by accepting your own answer.

Comment: @epimorphic alright, there is a 24 hour wait until I can approve my own anwser tho. Thank you for being clear about what the problem was.